# Not able to populate table view on JAVA FX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I'm new to JavaFX and in the application that I'm trying to develop there are two controllers: `ProductOverviewController` and `CartOverviewController`.

`ProductOverviewController` sends to `CartOverviewController` the `ObservableList` (trough `User` object) that would be displayed into the `CartOverviewController`'s table.

The problem is: `CartOverviewController` seems to receive the `Observablelist` (I tried to print an object's name contained in the observable list with good results), but when I run the program the table is empty.

I have already read all the previous discussion about this issue but I wasn't able to solve this problem.
This is the code:

1) ProductOverviewController

```
public class ProductOverviewController {


public static  User user;
public static Product product;
private MainApp mainApp;

//FXML tag is used to link view controller to the view
@FXML
private TableView<Product> productTable;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Product, String> productNameColumn;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Product, Double> productPriceColumn;

@FXML
private Label idLabel;
@FXML
private Label productNameLabel;
@FXML
private Label productPriceLabel;
@FXML
private Label productInfoLabel;
@FXML
private Label userLabel;

/*
 * Reference to the main app
 */




//constructor
public ProductOverviewController(){
}


//initializer. automatically called after fxml has been loaded
@FXML
private void initialize() throws SQLException, IOException{

    //Initialize Product table with 2 column
    productNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().productNameProperty());
    productPriceColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().productPriceProperty().asObject());

    /*THIS CODE IS FOR SYNCRONIZING
     *
     */

    //Clear person details

    showProductDetails(null);

    //Listen for changes and show details
    productTable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue)-> {
        try {
            showProductDetails(newValue);
            product = newValue;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

}

//is called by the main app to give a reference back to itself

public void setMainApp(MainApp mainApp){

    this.mainApp = mainApp;
    //add observable list to the table
    productTable.setItems(mainApp.getProductData());
}

//fill all text field with products'data in the right table

private void showProductDetails(Product product) throws SQLException, IOException{

    if(product != null){
        //fill table's labels
        idLabel.setText(Integer.toString(product.getIdProduct()));
        productNameLabel.setText(product.getProductName());
        productPriceLabel.setText(Double.toString(product.getProductPrice()));
        productInfoLabel.setText(product.getProductInfo());
        if(user != null && user.isLogin() == true){
            userLabel.setText(user.getUsername());
        }else if(user.isLogin() == false){
            userLabel.setText("Guest");
        }

    }else{

        idLabel.setText("");
        productNameLabel.setText("");
        productPriceLabel.setText("");
        productInfoLabel.setText("");


    }
}

@FXML
public void handleViewChart() throws IOException, SQLException{

    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("CartOverview.fxml"));
    Parent root;
    try{

        root = fxmlLoader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(scene);
        ((CartOverviewController)fxmlLoader.getController()).setUser(user);
        stage.show();
    }catch(IOException e){

        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}

@FXML
private void handleAddToCart(){ 
    //send to CartOverviewControler user with the dispaly list and print for debug
    user.addToCart(product);
    System.out.println(user.getCartList().get(0).getProductName());

}

}
```

2) CartOverviewController

```
public class CartOverviewController implements Initializable {

public User user;

private ObservableList<Product> cart = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

@FXML
private TableView<Product> productTable;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Product, String> productNameColumn;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Product, Double> productPriceColumn;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Product, Double> productAmountColumn;




public void setUser(User user) throws SQLException, IOException{

    this.user = user;
    this.cart = this.user.getCartList();
    System.out.println(this.cart.get(0).getProductName());
}


@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //Method 1
    /*
    productNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Product, String> ("productName"));
    productPriceColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Product, Double> ("productPrice"));
    productAmountColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Product, Double> ("productAmount"));
     */

    //Method 2

    productNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().productNameProperty());
    productPriceColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().productPriceProperty().asObject());
    productAmountColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().productPriceProperty().asObject());


    //added this for debug
    if(cart != null && productTable != null)
        productTable.setItems(cart);
    else if(cart == null)
        System.out.println("cart is null");
    else if(productTable == null)
        System.out.println("table is null");
    else
        System.out.println("else is null");
}


}
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call `productTable.setItems(cart)` in the `initialize()` method, which is executed *before* the `setUser()` method in which you call `cart = user.getCartList()`. You either need to set the table items again:

```
public void setUser(User user) throws SQLException, IOException{

    this.user = user;
    this.cart = this.user.getCartList();
    productTable.setItems(cart);
}
```

or just update the contents of the current `cart` list (instead of replacing it):

```
public void setUser(User user) throws SQLException, IOException{

    this.user = user;
    this.cart.setAll(this.user.getCartList());
}
```

Comment: Done, sorry I'm new also in Stack Overflow.. :)